# OpenSWAN does not start Phase2 at all

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, ipsec, openbsd

I want to connect my Ubuntu 12.04 developer box to corporate network. They have OpenBSD 5.1 on their router with isakmpd. The auth is being done by using RSA keys only.

On my side I'd installed openswan (apt-get install openswan) and did the set up:

```
# /etc/ipsec.conf - Openswan IPsec configuration file

# This file:  /usr/share/doc/openswan/ipsec.conf-sample
#
# Manual:     ipsec.conf.5


version 2.0     # conforms to second version of ipsec.conf specification

# basic configuration
config setup
        dumpdir=/var/run/pluto/
        nat_traversal=yes
        virtual_private=%v4:10.0.0.0/8,%v4:192.168.0.0/16,%v4:172.16.0.0/12,%v4:25.0.0.0/8,%v6:fd00::/8,%v6:fe80::/10
        # OE is now off by default. Uncomment and change to on, to enable.
        oe=off
        # which IPsec stack to use. auto will try netkey, then klips then mast
        protostack=netkey
        # Use this to log to a file, or disable logging on embedded systems (like openwrt)
        #plutostderrlog=/dev/null

# Add connections here
include /etc/ipsec.d/ipsec.*.conf
```

Here the set up of the connection:

```
conn office
        auto=start
        type=tunnel
        compress=yes
        aggrmode=no
        forceencaps=yes
        left=%defaultroute
        leftid=@andrey-ubuntu.example.com
        # To get the proper rsasigkey values, use ipsec showhostkey. On left (vpgw1) run: ipsec showhostkey --left
        leftrsasigkey=0sAwEAAavfJOtpFvA......big_key
        leftca=ca.crt
        leftsendcert=always
        # Convert PEM cert to der
        # openssl x509 -in andrey-ubuntu.pem -outform DER -out andrey-ubuntu.der
        leftcert=andrey-ubuntu.der
        #
        right=4.5.3.126
        rightid=@secure1.example.com
        rightrsasigkey=0sAwEAAc92q7qKyW......big_key
        #leftupdown="ipsec _updown --route yes" # See ipsec_pluto(8) for details. Relevant only locally, other end need not agree on it.
        ike=aes256-sha1;modp2048
        phase2alg=aes256-sha1;modp2048
        ikelifetime=28800s
        authby=rsasig
        pfs=yes
        salifetime=28800s
        keyexchange=ike
```

My workstation uses NAT. When I start openswan service, I see this in the logs of my machine:

```
Sep 17 06:15:25 zentavr-ig ipsec_setup: Starting Openswan IPsec U2.6.37/K3.5.0-23-generic...
Sep 17 06:15:25 zentavr-ig ipsec_setup: Using NETKEY(XFRM) stack
Sep 17 06:15:25 zentavr-ig kernel: [19389.748253] Initializing XFRM netlink socket
Sep 17 06:15:25 zentavr-ig ipsec_setup: ...Openswan IPsec started
Sep 17 06:15:25 zentavr-ig pluto: adjusting ipsec.d to /etc/ipsec.d
Sep 17 06:15:25 zentavr-ig ipsec__plutorun: adjusting ipsec.d to /etc/ipsec.d
Sep 17 06:15:25 zentavr-ig rsyslogd-2177: imuxsock begins to drop messages from pid 25281 due to rate-limiting
Sep 17 06:15:25 zentavr-ig ipsec__plutorun: 002 loading certificate from andrey-ubuntu.der
Sep 17 06:15:25 zentavr-ig ipsec__plutorun: 002   loaded host cert file '/etc/ipsec.d/certs/andrey-ubuntu.der' (893 bytes)
Sep 17 06:15:25 zentavr-ig ipsec__plutorun: 002 added connection description "office"
Sep 17 06:15:25 zentavr-ig ipsec__plutorun: 104 "office" #1: STATE_MAIN_I1: initiate
```

and more:

```
root@zentavr-ig:/etc/ipsec.d# ipsec auto status
ipsec auto: warning: obsolete command syntax used
000 using kernel interface: netkey
000 interface lo/lo ::1
000 interface lo/lo 127.0.0.1
000 interface lo/lo 127.0.0.1
000 interface eth0/eth0 172.16.30.254
000 interface eth0/eth0 172.16.30.254
000 %myid = (none)
000 debug raw+crypt+parsing+emitting+control+klips+pfkey+nattraversal+x509+dpd+private
000
000 virtual_private (%priv):
000 - allowed 6 subnets: 10.0.0.0/8, 192.168.0.0/16, 172.16.0.0/12, 25.0.0.0/8, fd00::/8, fe80::/10
000 - disallowed 0 subnets:
000 WARNING: Disallowed subnets in virtual_private= is empty. If you have
000          private address space in internal use, it should be excluded!
000
000 algorithm ESP encrypt: id=2, name=ESP_DES, ivlen=8, keysizemin=64, keysizemax=64
000 algorithm ESP encrypt: id=3, name=ESP_3DES, ivlen=8, keysizemin=192, keysizemax=192
000 algorithm ESP encrypt: id=6, name=ESP_CAST, ivlen=8, keysizemin=40, keysizemax=128
000 algorithm ESP encrypt: id=7, name=ESP_BLOWFISH, ivlen=8, keysizemin=40, keysizemax=448
000 algorithm ESP encrypt: id=11, name=ESP_NULL, ivlen=0, keysizemin=0, keysizemax=0
000 algorithm ESP encrypt: id=12, name=ESP_AES, ivlen=8, keysizemin=128, keysizemax=256
000 algorithm ESP encrypt: id=13, name=ESP_AES_CTR, ivlen=8, keysizemin=160, keysizemax=288
000 algorithm ESP encrypt: id=14, name=ESP_AES_CCM_A, ivlen=8, keysizemin=128, keysizemax=256
000 algorithm ESP encrypt: id=15, name=ESP_AES_CCM_B, ivlen=8, keysizemin=128, keysizemax=256
000 algorithm ESP encrypt: id=16, name=ESP_AES_CCM_C, ivlen=8, keysizemin=128, keysizemax=256
000 algorithm ESP encrypt: id=18, name=ESP_AES_GCM_A, ivlen=8, keysizemin=128, keysizemax=256
000 algorithm ESP encrypt: id=19, name=ESP_AES_GCM_B, ivlen=8, keysizemin=128, keysizemax=256
000 algorithm ESP encrypt: id=20, name=ESP_AES_GCM_C, ivlen=8, keysizemin=128, keysizemax=256
000 algorithm ESP encrypt: id=22, name=ESP_CAMELLIA, ivlen=8, keysizemin=128, keysizemax=256
000 algorithm ESP encrypt: id=252, name=ESP_SERPENT, ivlen=8, keysizemin=128, keysizemax=256
000 algorithm ESP encrypt: id=253, name=ESP_TWOFISH, ivlen=8, keysizemin=128, keysizemax=256
000 algorithm ESP auth attr: id=1, name=AUTH_ALGORITHM_HMAC_MD5, keysizemin=128, keysizemax=128
000 algorithm ESP auth attr: id=2, name=AUTH_ALGORITHM_HMAC_SHA1, keysizemin=160, keysizemax=160
000 algorithm ESP auth attr: id=5, name=AUTH_ALGORITHM_HMAC_SHA2_256, keysizemin=256, keysizemax=256
000 algorithm ESP auth attr: id=6, name=AUTH_ALGORITHM_HMAC_SHA2_384, keysizemin=384, keysizemax=384
000 algorithm ESP auth attr: id=7, name=AUTH_ALGORITHM_HMAC_SHA2_512, keysizemin=512, keysizemax=512
000 algorithm ESP auth attr: id=8, name=AUTH_ALGORITHM_HMAC_RIPEMD, keysizemin=160, keysizemax=160
000 algorithm ESP auth attr: id=9, name=AUTH_ALGORITHM_AES_CBC, keysizemin=128, keysizemax=128
000 algorithm ESP auth attr: id=251, name=(null), keysizemin=0, keysizemax=0
000
000 algorithm IKE encrypt: id=0, name=(null), blocksize=16, keydeflen=131
000 algorithm IKE encrypt: id=5, name=OAKLEY_3DES_CBC, blocksize=8, keydeflen=192
000 algorithm IKE encrypt: id=7, name=OAKLEY_AES_CBC, blocksize=16, keydeflen=128
000 algorithm IKE hash: id=1, name=OAKLEY_MD5, hashsize=16
000 algorithm IKE hash: id=2, name=OAKLEY_SHA1, hashsize=20
000 algorithm IKE dh group: id=2, name=OAKLEY_GROUP_MODP1024, bits=1024
000 algorithm IKE dh group: id=5, name=OAKLEY_GROUP_MODP1536, bits=1536
000 algorithm IKE dh group: id=14, name=OAKLEY_GROUP_MODP2048, bits=2048
000 algorithm IKE dh group: id=15, name=OAKLEY_GROUP_MODP3072, bits=3072
000 algorithm IKE dh group: id=16, name=OAKLEY_GROUP_MODP4096, bits=4096
000 algorithm IKE dh group: id=17, name=OAKLEY_GROUP_MODP6144, bits=6144
000 algorithm IKE dh group: id=18, name=OAKLEY_GROUP_MODP8192, bits=8192
000 algorithm IKE dh group: id=22, name=OAKLEY_GROUP_DH22, bits=1024
000 algorithm IKE dh group: id=23, name=OAKLEY_GROUP_DH23, bits=2048
000 algorithm IKE dh group: id=24, name=OAKLEY_GROUP_DH24, bits=2048
000
000 stats db_ops: {curr_cnt, total_cnt, maxsz} :context={0,1,64} trans={0,1,3072} attrs={0,1,2048}
000
000 "office": 172.16.30.254[@andrey-ubuntu.idle-games.com,+S=C]...4.5.3.126<204.15.3.126>[@secure1.example.com,+S=C]; prospective erouted; eroute owner: #0
000 "office":     myip=unset; hisip=unset; mycert=andrey-ubuntu.der;
000 "office":   CAs: '\011'...'%any'
000 "office":   ike_life: 28800s; ipsec_life: 28800s; rekey_margin: 540s; rekey_fuzz: 100%; keyingtries: 0
000 "office":   policy: RSASIG+ENCRYPT+COMPRESS+TUNNEL+PFS+UP+IKEv2ALLOW+SAREFTRACK; prio: 32,32; interface: eth0;
000 "office":   dpd: action:clear; delay:0; timeout:0;
000 "office":   newest ISAKMP SA: #0; newest IPsec SA: #0;
000 "office":   IKE algorithms wanted: AES_CBC(7)_256-SHA1(2)_000-MODP2048(14); flags=-strict
000 "office":   IKE algorithms found:  AES_CBC(7)_256-SHA1(2)_160-MODP2048(14)
000 "office":   ESP algorithms wanted: AES(12)_256-SHA1(2)_000; pfsgroup=MODP2048(14); flags=-strict
000 "office":   ESP algorithms loaded: AES(12)_256-SHA1(2)_160
000
000 #1: "office":4500 STATE_MAIN_I3 (sent MI3, expecting MR3); none in -1s; lastdpd=-1s(seq in:0 out:0); idle; import:admin initiate
000 #1: pending Phase 2 for "office" replacing #0
000
```

...and that's all. Onto the sevrers side we see:

```
@400000005237c9581197de3c 201526.295150 Default isakmpd: phase 1 done (as responder): initiator id andrey-ubuntu.example.com, responder id secure1.example.com, src: 4.5.3.126 dst: 1.18.7.156
@400000005237c9581d9d9c94 201526.496860 Default message_parse_payloads: reserved field non-zero: c3
@400000005237c9581d9db01c 201526.496867 Default dropped message from 1.8.7.156 port 1024 due to notification type PAYLOAD_MALFORMED
@400000005237c958298b3b24 201526.696975 Default message_recv: cleartext phase 2 message
@400000005237c958298b567c 201526.696984 Default dropped message from 1.18.7.156 port 1024 due to notification type INVALID_FLAGS
@400000005237c9621f5c4c24 201536.526130 Default message_recv: cleartext phase 2 message
@400000005237c9621f5c6394 201536.526140 Default dropped message from 1.18.7.156 port 1024 due to notification type INVALID_FLAGS
@400000005237c9672034702c 201541.540296 Default message_recv: cleartext phase 2 message
@400000005237c96720348b84 201541.540305 Default dropped message from 1.18.7.156 port 1024 due to notification type INVALID_FLAGS
@400000005237c96c22a335dc 201546.581110 Default message_recv: cleartext phase 2 message
@400000005237c96c22a34d4c 201546.581118 Default dropped message from 1.18.7.156 port 1024 due to notification type INVALID_FLAGS
@400000005237c9712389d8d4 201551.596225 Default message_recv: cleartext phase 2 message
@400000005237c9712389ec5c 201551.596233 Default dropped message from 1.18.7.156 port 1024 due to notification type INVALID_FLAGS
@400000005237c97625f0e9dc 201556.636531 Default message_recv: cleartext phase 2 message
@400000005237c97625f0fd64 201556.636542 Default dropped message from 1.18.7.156 port 1024 due to notification type INVALID_FLAGS
```

OpeBSDs isakmpd is done in this kind:

```
ike passive esp tunnel                                  \
        from any to any                                 \
        main auth hmac-sha1 enc aes-256 group modp2048  \
        quick auth hmac-sha1 enc aes-256 group modp2048 \
        srcid secure1.example.com                \
        tag ipsec-$id
```

I wonder: why openSWAN cannot start phase2 at all and on serverside i see such strange errors? My ideas were depleted after several nights of debugging :(

Answer (score 0):

Invalid flags makes me wonder if perhaps compression or another setting you have enabled on one side isn't compatible with the other.  I almost always use compression=no on OpenSWAN to avoid compatibility issues myself.